# Unity 2019.1 and Vuforia : OPENGL NATIVE PLUG-IN ERROR

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm trying to switch between two scenes in my app. I have one AR scene *(main)* and another not-AR (*Tutorial*).

The main scene is working fine but when I change to the tutorial and come back, the camera is zoomed but the tracking still works. I have to restart the app if I want to be able to use it again.

Also it is working really fine in the editor, but not in build on android devices.

I'm on **Unity 2019.1.0a8** and I use **Vuforia 7.5.26**. And I use **GLES 2.0**  Graphic API and **.NET 4.x** scripting runtime.

I configured Vuforia to use *Delayed Initialization* and I initialize Vuforia like this with a behaviour attached to the AR Camera :

```
void Start()
{
    VuforiaRuntime.Instance.InitVuforia();
    GetComponent<VuforiaBehaviour>().enabled = true;
}
```

Here's the logcat of the issue :

```
Unity   : StartVuforia
Unity   : (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 48)
Unity   : OPENGL NATIVE PLUG-IN ERROR: GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Operation illegal in current state
Unity   : (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/GfxDevice/opengles/GfxDeviceGLES.cpp Line: 347)
```

This was observed on :

- Samsung Galaxy S7, Android 8.0.0
- Samsung Galaxy Tab S4, Android 8.1.0

Also, I'm trying to get the `TextureBufferCamera` GameObject created at the start of the scene by Vuforia. I'm able to get it in the Editor but not in Android Build, any idea why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I tried different things, like switching to **GLES 3.0** or **Vulkan**. But no success. So I switched back to **GLES 2.0**.

I just tried with downgrading to **.NET 3.5** scripting runtime and had to refactor some piece of code. And it worked.

I post this as an answer so it can help someone else, but if someone has any explanation about the reason behind this, I will gladly mark his answer as the correct one.

Comment: My guess is that Vuforia is .net 3.5, but as 2019 is very much an alpha product its not too surprising that stuff doesnt work well.

Comment: Well everything is working really fine right now, it was just this .NET 3.5 issue, since .NET 4.x is supported by 2019 version, it is default when  you start a new project...

Comment: Right but Vuforia do not mention 2019 support, in fact i havent found anything for unity 2018 on their site, and that had many game breaking changes in it alone.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it.

Unity version: 2019.2.16f1

follow these steps:

first: go to Project Settings >>> Player >>> Other Settings.

second: find "Auto Graphic API" and uncheck it.

third: Now you can see a new panel just below the "Auto Graphic API". It's a list of "Graphics APIs". Remove all graphics APIs and just add "OpenGLES2".